# Throwing Exceptions Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin.ios

I am wondering if i am able to get a method to throw an exception similarly to the below Java code.

```
    private void iAmChecked() throws FileNotFoundException {
     FileReader fr = new FileReader("Not Here.txt");
    }
```

I am currently developing an Android Application using Xamarin, I want the app to display a Dialog message if internet connection is lost. I am wrapping the appropriate method calls within the OnCreate with a try catch. The Catch will display a Dialog message and then terminate the application. I am aiming for the methods to throw an error back to the onCreate method so that I can do this.

I am wondering a few points.

- Are there better ways of doing this
- How can i replicate the above Java code in c#
- Will it work

Thanks, 
Joe

Comment: That code doesn't fires any exception by itself, it only indicates it can throw an exception, but not by itself but by the functions called inside it. On C# that's unnecesary, you don't need to specify what kind of exceptions your code can throw.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't fires any exception by itself, it only indicates it can throw an exception, but not by itself but by the functions called inside it. On C# that's unnecesary, you don't need to specify what kind of exceptions your code can throw.

There is a better way of doing this:

```
bool AmIChecked()
{
    return System.IO.File.Exists("Not Here.txt");
}
```